# Removing thumbnail, single product page link from products of a specific product category

Tags: woocommerce

i am trying to remove thumbnail, single product page link from products of a specific product category and display them in a table with product name, product attribute,add to cart button.
I succeded in removing the product link using `remove_action`

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

But it removed product links from all category,

Please tell me how to write an if statement so that it will only remove link from a certain product category.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from this answer on
[Stackoverflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67247/how-to-display-product-specific-to-a-category-with-woocommerce-plugin)
,posting here so that others can benefit from it.